# Store php code rules in database

Tags: php, mysql, eval

Currently Im designing db and architecture of a web-site with delivery providers.

Some providers have static delivery price, there are no problems, but some of them have dynamically calculated price. For example:

```
if ({{item_type}} == 1)
   $price = {{default_price}} - {{default_price}} * 0.5;
else
   $price = {{default_price}};
// {{...}} values are in sql tables
```

The amount of providers is huge an should be easy addable, so I can't hard-code such rules for each in php.

My idea was to store store such rules as a string it sql column and workflow should looks like:

```
select_rule -> parse_{{}}_values -> preg_replace_{{}}_values ->
               eval(selected&parsed_rule) -> use_$price_variable
```

But I'm not fully confident that it is best and efficient solution, or will it work at all. What do you think?

Are there more suitable solutions? Maybe someone has already had such challenge and found a good way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst technically possible, it'd be a security risk to execute code directly stored in the database. It'd make more sense to add fields to cater for the ways a price can changes (provider_markup, provider_discount, provider_shipping, etc.) and build your code to utilise those.

Comment: Absolutely agree about additional fields - they should give a better design. But the problem is that in my situation my site should adapt to provides, not they and the variety of their pricing may differ greatly. For example, for item_type=2 it may be fully free of charge, or for 2xItem_Type=1 (in basket).
Maybe are some other ideas? If not, how can I make  `eval` more securely?

Comment: I'd then look at adding columns (shipping, free_shipping_threshold, etc.) to the item table also. You could build in such a way that item shipping overrides provider shipping in order to satisfy business rules. 

If you still think this is unworkable then I'd look at defining the rules outside of user-writable database. Something like a flat config file to define an array of rules and let the database store a reference to that array. If you still wanted to define in a database I'd look at using a whitelist of words and characters to allow, especially for code executed server side.

Comment: Don't use eval for this.  Read up on database normalization.  It wouldn't hurt if you learned OOP, as well.

Comment: @KevinM1 Thank you, of course, for you proposition, but your comment completely isn't constructive. I have an architectural problem that i asked community to help me with a solution. As i said, `eval` is a bad design and i know it. And i didn't touch code&oop here at all.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that normalizing your database will solve most of your problems.  It's never a good idea to store **a** string of config values in a database.  Instead, you create a normalized db from which you can grab the data, and to which you can easily insert new data (likely with an ORM, which is where OOP would come in).  You could then build entities (more OOP) on the fly in order to deal with those constraints in real time in your code.  I know it all sounds vague, but your initial question was vague, and you lack the basic tools to handle anything complex.

Comment: Database normalization and OOP *are* those tools.  You'll need to learn them if you want to do this professionally.  That's why I'm suggesting them.  `eval` is a bad code smell, one which generally comes from a lack of experience and knowledge of modern programming techniques.  My sense is that you need to brush up on and/or learn some of the basics.

Comment: If you know database normalization, you should be able to come to a solution.  I mean that with no malice.  That your first thoughts on solving this problem were to hard code the config, or to store the data as strings you'd need to parse via regex shows me you *don't* actually know normalization.  @scoota269 gave you a great starting point.  And, if you want *specific* help, you should edit your question to show everyone an example of the kind of configuration string you were thinking of creating.  Your question is vague, to the point where generalized advice is all anyone can give.